# MVC populate dropdown from foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreign-keys, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been struggling with this for several days.  I need to populate a dropdownlistfor with genres.

My MovieRepository to grab the genres:

```
public IQueryable<Movies> MoviesAndGenres
{
        get { return db.Movies.Include(m => m.parentGenre); }
}
```

My movie model

```
public virtual Genres parentGenre { get; set; }
```

Genre Model:

```
public class Genres
{
    public Genres()
    {
        this.movies = new HashSet<Movies>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int genreId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A genre name is required")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public String genreName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Movies> movies { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to pass in the genres with a select list, but I am getting a LINQ to Entities does not recognize the System.String To String() Method, and this method cannot be translated to a stored expression.

Movies Controller, addMovie action:

```
ViewBag.Genres = movieRepository.MoviesAndGenres.Select(m => new SelectListItem 
        {
            Text = m.parentGenre.genreName,
            Value = m.parentGenre.genreId.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        return View();
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, (SelectList)ViewBag.Genres)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update:

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<Genres> MoviesAndGenres
{
        get { return db.Genres; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var x = movieRepository.MoviesAndGenres.Select(m => new 
        {
            Text = m.genreName,
            Value = m.genreId
        });

        ViewBag.Genres = new SelectList(x);
        return View();
```

View:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, (SelectList)ViewBag.Genres)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're retrieving all of the records anyways, you can just do this.

```
ViewBag.Genres = movieRepository.MoviesAndGenres.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem 
    {
        Text = m.parentGenre.genreName,
        Value = m.parentGenre.genreId.ToString()
    });
```

You would also need to change your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres))
```

Actually, a better approach would probably be this, since then it only retrieves the specific columns you need:

```
var x = movieRepository.MoviesAndGenres.Select(m => new 
    {
        Text = m.parentGenre.genreName,
        Value = m.parentGenre.genreId
    });

ViewBag.Genres = new SelectList(x)
```

Also, the ToList() is no longer required because it's already in a an immediate state.

Comment: It won't run - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: I get this error in my view: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[MovieRental.Models.Movies,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

Comment: I changed my view to the code below, but my dropdown is empty.  I checked the database and there are records in there.  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Genres)

Comment: @Andrew - Because Genres is not a SelectList.  It's an Enumerable of SelectListItem (prior to this it was a List of SelectListItem).  Neither are SelectLists.  You need to create a new SelectList.  See my update

Comment: I tried your new update and it's still empty.  I changed my view back to the original.  Do you think it may be an issue with my repository?

Comment: @Andrew - Have you looked at the result set in your Method with the debugger?  It will say how many records are in the returned result set.

Comment: It shows the query, but I don't see where it has the count.  I checked the action and the repository.

Comment: You need to click the refresh button in the debugger (looks like a circle with two arrows circling around in it) on the Results View field (where it says Expanding the results will Enumerate the IEnumerable.  You could also just add a variable to your code that is `int i = x.Count();` and then check that in the debugger.

Comment: The value is returning zero.

Comment: The movies table is empty if that makes a difference.  I just need to grab all of the genres.

Comment: @Andrew - what does your query in your repository look like? You are probably doing a join which would not return any records because there are no movies.  You probably need a method called Genres that just returns Genres.

Comment: That's what I was doing.  I just changed it to return db.Genres and that fixed it partially.  It's now loading "{ Text = Comdedy, Value = 2}" in the drop down.

Comment: @Andrew - please update your question (add to the end, don't change your existing code) with what you are doing now in the action method and in the form.

Comment: @Andrew, change your code to `ViewBag.Genres = new SelectList(x, "Value", "Text");`